# É possível criar um certificado em formato PFX e definir um OID para alguns parâmetros?

Tags: java, certificado-digital

Estou precisando gerar um certificado para simular um e-CPF.
Estou criando uma implementação para consultar e validar as informações de certificados digitais e-CPF e e-CNPJ com minha aplicação.

A parte de extração já tenho pronta mas não tenho um certificado digital e-CPF para testar.

Consegui criar o certificado em formato PFX com o Keytool do Java, porém não consigo especificar nenhum *Object Identifier* (OID) para o certificado durante a criação.

Preciso especificar 2 OID's, um irá conter uma string com CPF e o outro OID irá conter o nome do responsável pelo certificado.
Estas são informações que vem por padrão no certificado digital e-CPF e e-CNPJ.

Consultando [este *layout*](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/acsrf/LeiautedeCertificadosdaSRF.pdf) consegui descobrir os OID's correspondentes para o e-CPF.

São eles:

- `2.16.76.1.3.2` = Para o responsável
- `2.16.76.1.3.1` = Contém uma série de informações como data de nascimento da pessoa física titular do certificado, CPF entre outras informações

O que seria relevante deste campo para mim seria o CPF, já tenho preparada a extração desta informação, me falta apenas conseguir gerar o certificado com o e-CPF.

E o comando que estou utilizando para gerar o PFX é este:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore meuCertificado.pfx -storetype PKCS12 -storepass 123456 -alias CERTIFICADO_PARA_TESTES -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 99999 -dname "CN=Meu Cert Teste, OU=TESTE, OU=Certificado PF A1, O=MinhaEmpresa, L=MinhaCidade, ST=Minas Gerais, C=SA" -ext san=dns:mydomain.com,dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para começar, alguns detalhes:

O OID `2.16.76.1.3.1` não contém somente o CPF, e sim uma série de informações que devem estar no formato correto para que os dados do certificado sejam lidos corretamente. O próprio documento que você citou diz o seguinte:

> Nas primeiras 8 (oito) posições, a data de nascimento da pessoa física titular do certificado, no formato ddmmaaaa; nas 11 (onze) posições subseqüentes, o número de inscrição no Cadastro de Pessoa Física (CPF) da pessoa física titular do certificado; nas 11 (onze) posições subseqüentes, o número de Identificação Social da pessoa física titular do certificado - NIS (PIS, PASEP ou CI); nas 15 (quinze) posições subseqüentes, o número do Registro Geral - RG da pessoa física titular do certificado; nas 6 (seis) posições subseqüentes, as siglas do órgão expedidor do RG e respectiva UF.

Lembrando que o título de eleitor e o RG são opcionais, seguindo estas regras (também explicadas no mesmo documento):

> Quando os números de NIS (PIS/PASEP/CI) RG, CEI, ou Titulo de Eleitor não estiverem disponíveis, os campos correspondentes devem ser integralmente preenchidos com
> caracteres “zero”.
>
> Se o número do RG ou o número de inscrição do Titulo de Eleitor não estiver disponível, não se deve preencher os campos de órgão expedidor e UF ou os campos Zona Eleitoral, Sessão, Município e UF, respectivamente.
>
> Todas informações de tamanho variável, referentes a números, tais como RG, devem ser preenchidas com caracteres “zero” a sua esquerda para que seja completado seu máximo
> tamanho possível.
>
> As 6 (seis) posições das informações sobre órgão expedidor do RG e UF referem-se ao tamanho máximo, devendo ser utilizadas apenas as posições necessárias ao seu armazenamento, da esquerda para a direita.

Portanto, não basta colocar só o CPF neste OID. As aplicações que lêem os dados do certificado procuram os campos nas posições corretas, e colocar campos em formatos errados não vai funcionar.

Outro ponto é que o eCPF deve ter também os OID's `2.16.76.1.3.5` e `2.16.76.1.3.6`, cujos formatos também são descritos em detalhes no mesmo documento que você citou.

Há também detalhes sobre a ordem em que estes OID's aparecem. As Políticas de Certificado [da AC Serasa](https://serasa.certificadodigital.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/PC_A1_AC_Serasa_RFB.pdf) e da [AC Certisign](http://icp-brasil.certisign.com.br/repositorio/pc/AC_Certisign_RFB/PC_AC_Certisign_RFB_A1_V5.1.pdf), por exemplo, dizem que a ordem dos OID's deve ser `2.16.76.1.3.1`, `2.16.76.1.3.6` e `2.16.76.1.3.5`. Já o documento que você citou não diz nada sobre a ordem dos mesmos.

---

Já o eCNPJ deve ter os OID's `2.16.76.1.3.4`, `2.16.76.1.3.2`, `2.16.76.1.3.3` e `2.16.76.1.3.7` (e novamente, as AC's mencionam que deve estar nesta ordem, mas o documento da Receita não), e cada um tem o seu formato próprio, de maneira similar aos campos do eCPF.

#### E como eu gero isso?

O `keytool` possui a opção `-ext` para colocar extensões no certificado. Como os OID's ficam na extensão [Subject Alternative Name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6), bastaria colocar esta extensão. Algo assim:

```
keytool -genkeypair ..... -ext san=oid:2.16.76.1.3.1,oid:2.16.76.1.3.6,oid:2.16.76.1.3.5
```

Infelizmente, não consegui passar os valores para os OID's, pois o keytool parece suportar apenas o próprio número do OID como o valor.

Então o jeito é usar o próprio Java mesmo. Eu fiz um código que gera um certificado de AC qualquer (gravando os arquivos "actest.jks", com a chave privada da AC, e "actest.cer", com o certificado da AC, caso precise adicionar em algum truststore, por exemplo).

Em seguida, eu uso a chave privada que está em "actest.jks" e uso-a para gerar um e-CPF ou e-CNPJ (também salvando em PFX e o .cer com somente o certificado). O detalhe é que usei o [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/), uma biblioteca que recomendo **muito** para trabalhar com certificados (e criptografia em geral). Como estou usando Maven, coloquei estas dependências:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.57</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.57</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bctls-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.57</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.57</version>
</dependency>
```

Mas se quiser, pode baixar esta versão no site https://www.bouncycastle.org/.

Como originalmente fiz este código em Java 7, usei também o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que é uma biblioteca de datas:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Mas se estiver usando Java >= 8, pode removê-la e usar o pacote `java.time` (há comentários no código a respeito disso, mas basicamente basta trocar o `import` de `org.threeten.bp` por `java.time`, exceto no caso da classe `DateTimeUtils`, que está comentado abaixo como proceder).

Primeiro a classe que cria o certificado e as chaves da AC:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CertificatePolicies;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.ExtendedKeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyQualifierId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyQualifierInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509ExtensionUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class CriarAcTest {

    private static JcaX509ExtensionUtils extUtils;

    static SecureRandom rand;
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            extUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            rand = new SecureRandom();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cria um novo certificado de AC (a partir do qual serão emitidos outros certificados)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPair acKeyPair = genKeyPair(4096);

        String acSubject = "C=BR,O=TRT2,CN=AC Test";
        // criar AC com validade de 30 anos (365 * 30)
        X509Certificate acCert = createAcCert(acSubject, new BigInteger("1234"), 365 * 30, acKeyPair);
        saveToKeystore(acCert, acKeyPair.getPrivate(), "actest.jks", "JKS");
        saveToFile(acCert, "actest.cer");

        System.out.println(acCert);
    }

    static void saveToKeystore(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privKey, String file, String type) throws Exception {
        char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
        ks.load(null, password);

        ks.setKeyEntry("main", privKey, password, new Certificate[] { certificate });

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ks.store(out, password);
        out.close();
    }

    static void saveToFile(X509Certificate cert, String filename) throws IOException {
        JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        pw.writeObject(cert);
        pw.close();
    }

    static X509Certificate createAcCert(String subject, BigInteger serialNumber, int validityInDays, KeyPair keyPair) throws Exception {
        X500Name issuer = new X500Name(subject);
        // data-inicio 24 horas antes, pra evitar dessincronizacao entre maquinas, horario de verao
        Instant validityStart = Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        Instant validityEnd = validityStart.plus(validityInDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serialNumber,
           // se estiver usando Java >= 8, use o java.time e troque esta linha para Date.from(validityStart), Date.from(validityEnd)
           DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityStart), DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityEnd),
           issuer, keyPair.getPublic());

        KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(
            KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.keyCertSign | KeyUsage.cRLSign);
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);

        ExtendedKeyUsage eku = new ExtendedKeyUsage(new KeyPurposeId[] { KeyPurposeId.id_kp_OCSPSigning, KeyPurposeId.id_kp_timeStamping });
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, eku);

        BasicConstraints bc = new BasicConstraints(true);
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, bc);

        boolean isCritical = true;
        PolicyQualifierInfo pqInfo = new PolicyQualifierInfo("http://www.test.com");
        PolicyInformation policyInfo = new PolicyInformation(PolicyQualifierId.id_qt_cps, new DERSequence(pqInfo));
        CertificatePolicies policies = new CertificatePolicies(policyInfo);
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.certificatePolicies, isCritical, policies);

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, true, extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(keyPair.getPublic()));

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, true, extUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(keyPair.getPublic()));

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA512WithRSAEncryption").setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
            .build(keyPair.getPrivate());
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));

        return cert;
    }

    static KeyPair genKeyPair(int size) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        gen.initialize(size, rand);
        return gen.generateKeyPair();
    }
}
```

Código que lê o certificado da AC e gera um eCPF (você pode mudar o `main` para gerar um eCNPJ também, basta mudar os parâmetros):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERPrintableString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.ExtendedKeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509ExtensionUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class CriarCertificadoTest {

    private static JcaX509ExtensionUtils extUtils;

    static SecureRandom rand;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            extUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            rand = new SecureRandom();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cria um certificado de teste.
     *
     * O certificado é emitido pela AC criada pela classe {@link CriarAcTest}
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPair myKeyPair = genKeyPair(2048);

        String acSubject = "C=BR,O=TRT2,CN=AC Test";
        char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        // carrega o certificado da AC
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("actest.jks");
        ks.load(in, password);
        in.close();

        // obtém o certificado e as chaves da AC
        X509Certificate acCert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate("main");
        KeyPair acKeyPair = new KeyPair(acCert.getPublicKey(), (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("main", password));

        System.out.println(acCert);

        // mudar os dados conforme necessário
        String cpf = "23446147292";
        String filename = "cpf" + cpf;
        String nome = "FULANO DE TAL";
        filename = "certificado_" + cpf; // nome do PFX e .cer
        // validade do certificado (em dias) - a data inicial é a atual menos 24 horas
        int validityDays = 365 * 3;
        X509Certificate cert = createCert("C=BR,O=ICP-Brasil,OU=AR Teste,OU=RFB e-CPF A3,OU=TESTE,CN=" + nome + ":" + cpf,
                new BigInteger("3333333333", 16), validityDays, myKeyPair, acKeyPair, acSubject, cpf, acCert);
        saveToKeystore(cert, myKeyPair.getPrivate(), filename + ".pfx", "PKCS12", acCert);
        saveToFile(cert, filename + ".cer");

        System.out.println(cert);
    }

    static void saveToKeystore(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privKey, String file, String type, X509Certificate acCert) throws Exception {
        char[] password = "123456".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
        ks.load(null, password);

        ks.setKeyEntry("main", privKey, password, new Certificate[] { certificate, acCert });

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ks.store(out, password);
        out.close();
    }

    static void saveToFile(X509Certificate cert, String filename) throws IOException {
        JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        pw.writeObject(cert);
        pw.close();
    }

    public static X509Certificate createCert(String subject, BigInteger serialNumber, int validityInDays, KeyPair myKeyPair, KeyPair acKeyPair,
            String acSubject, String cpf, X509Certificate acCert)
            throws Exception {
        // data-inicio 24 horas antes, pra evitar dessincronizacao entre maquinas, horario de verao
        Instant validityStart = Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        Instant validityEnd = validityStart.plus(validityInDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        // data de validade do certificado não pode ser maior que da AC
        // a partir do Java 8, troque esta linha por acCert.getNotAfter().toInstant();
        Instant validadeAC = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(acCert.getNotAfter());
        if (!validityEnd.isBefore(validadeAC)) {
            validityEnd = validadeAC.minus(24 * 20, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        }
        X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name(acSubject), serialNumber,
            // se estiver usando Java >= 8, use o java.time e troque esta linha para Date.from(validityStart), Date.from(validityEnd)
            DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityStart), DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityEnd),
            new X500Name(subject), myKeyPair.getPublic());

        KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.nonRepudiation);
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);

        ExtendedKeyUsage eku = new ExtendedKeyUsage(new KeyPurposeId[] { KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth });
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, eku);

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(myKeyPair.getPublic()));

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, extUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(acKeyPair.getPublic()));

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Subject Alternative Names
        ASN1EncodableVector subjAltNames = new ASN1EncodableVector();

        // OID 1
        ASN1EncodableVector otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.1"));
        // data de nascimento
        StringBuilder strOid1 = new StringBuilder("10101970")
                // CPF
                .append(cpf)
                // nis
                .append("00000000000")
                // RG
                .append("000000226148452SSPSP");
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(strOid1.toString())));
        ASN1Object oid1 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid1);

        // OID 6
        otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.6"));
        // CEI
        String strOid6 = "000000000000";
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(strOid6)));
        ASN1Object oid6 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid6);

        // OID 5
        otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.5"));
        // titulo de eleitor
        StringBuilder strOid5 = new StringBuilder("850544450191")
                // zona eleitoral
                .append("001")
                // secao
                .append("0401")
                // municipio e UF
                .append("SAO PAULOSP");
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(strOid5.toString())));
        ASN1Object oid5 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid5);

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, new DERSequence(subjAltNames));
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                .build(acKeyPair.getPrivate());
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));

        return cert;
    }

    public static X509Certificate createCertPJ(String subject, BigInteger serialNumber, int validityInDays, KeyPair myKeyPair, KeyPair acKeyPair,
            String acSubject, String cpfResp, String nomeResp, String cnpj, X509Certificate acCert)
            throws Exception {
        // data-inicio 24 horas antes, pra evitar dessincronizacao entre maquinas, horario de verao
        Instant validityStart = Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        Instant validityEnd = validityStart.plus(validityInDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        // data de validade do certificado não pode ser maior que da AC
        // a partir do Java 8, troque esta linha por acCert.getNotAfter().toInstant();
        Instant validadeAC = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(acCert.getNotAfter());
        if (!validityEnd.isBefore(validadeAC)) {
            validityEnd = validadeAC.minus(24 * 20, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        }
        X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name(acSubject), serialNumber,
            // se estiver usando Java >= 8, use o java.time e troque esta linha para Date.from(validityStart), Date.from(validityEnd)
            DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityStart), DateTimeUtils.toDate(validityEnd),
            new X500Name(subject), myKeyPair.getPublic());

        KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.nonRepudiation);
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);

        ExtendedKeyUsage eku = new ExtendedKeyUsage(new KeyPurposeId[] { KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth });
        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, eku);

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(myKeyPair.getPublic()));

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, extUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(acKeyPair.getPublic()));

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Subject Alternative Names
        ASN1EncodableVector subjAltNames = new ASN1EncodableVector();

        // OID 4
        ASN1EncodableVector otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.4"));
        // data de nascimento
        StringBuilder strOid1 = new StringBuilder("10101970")
                // CPF
                .append(cpfResp)
                // nis
                .append("00000000000")
                // RG
                .append("000000226148452SSPSP");
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(strOid1.toString())));
        ASN1Object oid4 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid4);

        // OID 2
        otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.2"));
        // Nome do responsavel
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(nomeResp)));
        ASN1Object oid2 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid2);

        // OID 3
        otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.3"));
        // CNPJ
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(cnpj)));
        ASN1Object oid3 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid3);

        // OID 7
        otherName = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        otherName.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.76.1.3.7"));
        // CEI
        String strOid7 = "000000000000";
        otherName.add(new DERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DERPrintableString(strOid7)));
        ASN1Object oid7 = new DERTaggedObject(false, GeneralName.otherName, new DERSequence(otherName));
        subjAltNames.add(oid7);

        certBuilder.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, new DERSequence(subjAltNames));
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                .build(acKeyPair.getPrivate());
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));

        return cert;
    }

    public static KeyPair genKeyPair(int size) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        gen.initialize(size, rand);
        return gen.generateKeyPair();
    }
}
```

Fiz esse código há algum tempo e para rodar poucas vezes, o que é uma grande desculpa para estar tão cheio de redundâncias e sem nenhuma otimização. Fique à vontade para alterá-lo.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Vou testar aqui. Iria corrigir a parte dos OID conter mais coisas mas como não tenho muitos pontos no stackoverflow ainda não tenho permissão de edição.

Comment: @GladsonBruno Qual parte vc ia corrigir? Se foi na minha resposta, vc pode sugerir uma edição. Fique à vontade para corrigir, faz um tempo que não lia esses pdf's e posso ter deixado passar algum detalhe

Comment: seria a correção da descrição do OID que eu havia dito que continha apenas o CPF e a formatação da pergunta que saiu toda sem formatação.
Creio que consegui o privilégio de edição agora.

Comment: hktosubo muito obrigado.
Resolver meu problema com o certificado E-CPF
Estava a horas procurando como fazer isso no keytool

Comment: Estou com um problema diferente, o certificado de cliente gerado funcionou, porém a cadeia de certificados que tentei gerar não é válida, poderia dar uma olhada @hkotsubo? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382087/gerar-certificados-a1-para-teste-no-padr%c3%a3o-icp-brasil