# Demoiselle Signer erro ao assinar certificado CRLRepositoryException

Tags: java, spring, certificado-digital, openssl, demoiselle-certificate

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando o framework Demoiselle Signer [Demoiselle Signer](https://www.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br/v3/signer/). Porém eu não estou conseguindo assinar o documento com o certificado gerado. Sempre gera o seguinte erro:

> org.demoiselle.signer.core.repository.CRLRepositoryException: Não foi possível recuperar um endereço válido de LCR (lista de certificados revogados) no certificado.

Código do projeto:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/certificate", params= {"path"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] assinaturaCadesDetached(@RequestParam("path")String pathFileTxt) throws Exception {
    byte[] content = readContent(pathFileTxt);
    X509Certificate[] certificates = new X509Certificate[1];
    CAdESSigner singer = (CAdESSigner) new PKCS7Factory().factoryDefault();

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/rcarauta/desenvolvimento/certificado/client.der"));

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(readContent("/home/rcarauta/desenvolvimento/certificado/client.der"));

    certificates[0] = getCertificate();
    singer.setCertificates(certificates);

    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = factory.generatePrivate(spec);

    Configuration config = Configuration.getInstance();
    config.setOnline(false);    

    singer.setPrivateKey(privKey);

    return singer.doDetachedSign(content);

}


 private X509Certificate getCertificate() throws IOException, Exception {
    String pathFile = "/home/rcarauta/desenvolvimento/certificado/client.crt";
    ByteArrayInputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(readContent(pathFile));
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");           
    return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(bytes);
}

  private byte[] readContent(String pathFileTxt) throws IOException {
     return Files.readAllBytes(new File(pathFileTxt).toPath());
 }
```

Passo a passo de como foi gerado os certificados

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 4096

openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

openssl x509 -in client.crt -out client.pem -outform PEM

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.pem -outform DER -nocrypt -out private.der
```

Comment: Faltou colocar a extensão CDP (CRL Distribution Point) no certificado, veja exemplos de como fazer [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023746) e [aqui](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1445498968-Generate-certificate-with-cRLDistributionPoints-extension-using-OpenSSL)

Comment: Também dá pra usar o próprio Java para gerar os certificados, vc pode usar como base o código [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358199/112052), e adicionar o CDP adaptando [estes exemplos](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CRLDistPoint). Outro caminho é ver na documentação do demoiselle se tem como desabilitar a verificação de CRL (eu não conheço o demoiselle, mas já vi APIs que possuem esta opção)