# Gerar certificados A1 para teste no padrão ICP-BRASIL

Tags: apache, ssl, certificado-digital, openssl, httpd

Preciso gerar um certificado digital FAKE com o padrão utilizado pela ICP-BRASIL para teste de sistemas com os seguintes arquivos:

**1.** Cadeia de Certificados (Pro sistema identificar o certificado quando importado no navegador)

**2.** Certificado do Cliente (Pra se autenticar no sistema)

Se faz necessário a cadeia de certificados para que o servidor apache identifique os clientes que utilizam aquela AC.

Utilizei o código-fonte da resposta dessa pergunta e não obtive êxito, pois ele não gera uma cadeia de certificados, o certificado do usuário aparenta ser válido:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358172/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-criar-um-certificado-pfx-e-definir-um-oid-para-alguns-par%c3%a2metros#*=*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358172/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-criar-um-certificado-pfx-e-definir-um-oid-para-alguns-par%C3%A2metros#_=_)

Tentei gerar uma cadeia de certificados utilizando o arquivo JKS gerado, a mesma reconhece o certificado do cliente, porém ao tentar logar no sistema com o certificado gerado, o mesmo retorna o seguinte erro:

***Ocorreu um erro durante uma conexão com sembarreiras.local. O sistema remoto não reconhece e não considera confiável a CA que expediu o seu certificado. Código do erro: SSL_ERROR_UNKNOWN_CA_ALERT***

Comment: Vc precisa instalar o certificado da AC no browser (como autoridade certificadora confiável), para que ele confie no certificado. E precisa instalar no apache tb. Como essa AC é "fake", por padrão nenhum browser ou servidor considera ela confiável, a não ser que vc instale a mesma

Comment: O código da outra pergunta gera uma cadeia mais simplificada, pois tem só o certificado da AC e do cliente. Mas na vida real a cadeia ainda tem mais dois intermediários, totalizando 4 (raiz, receita, AC vinculada à receita e cliente), então se quiser pode adaptar aquele código para gerar a cadeia completa (mas de qq forma vai precisar instalar como confiável no browser e no servidor)